# How to convert CIDR to IP ranges using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, cidr

How to convert list like:

```
94.192.0.0/14  
94.0.0.0/12  
93.96.0.0/16
```

To:

```
94.192.0.0-94.195.255.255  
94.0.0.0-94.15.255.255  
93.96.0.0-93.96.255.255
```

Using python3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) builtin module:

```
>>> import ipaddress

>>> net=ipaddress.ip_network('94.192.0.0/14')
IPv4Network('94.192.0.0/14')

>>> '%s-%s' % (net[0], net[-1])
'94.192.0.0-94.195.255.255'
```

With `for i in net` you can also enumerate **all** ip addresses in the network `net`.